# MySQL converting a substring losing number after decimal

Tags: mysql, regex, substring

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(pluginText,LOCATE('cvss', pluginText), 21) AS CVSS_Base_Score_Text,
    CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(pluginText,
        LOCATE('cvss', pluginText), 21),' : ',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)
    AS CVSS_Base_Score_Number
FROM vulnerabilities_internal
WHERE LCASE(pluginText) REGEXP '.*cvss.*'
```

And it is returning 2 columns

```
CVSS_Base_Score_Text         CVSS_Base_Score Number
CVSS Base Score: 4.3         4
```

How can I modify this query so the number in the CVSS_Base_Score_Number column carries over the decimal point and displays as 4.3 ?

ANSWERED MY OWN QUESTION:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(pluginText,LOCATE('cvss', pluginText), 21) AS CVSS_Base_Score_Text,
CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(pluginText,LOCATE('cvss', pluginText), 21),' : ',  
-1), 
DECIMAL(10,1)) AS CVSS_Base_Score_Number
FROM vulnerabilities_internal
```

Comment: Please post your answer as an actual answer to the question (and subsequently accept it), so this question shows up as 'answered' in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(pluginText,LOCATE('cvss', pluginText), 21) AS CVSS_Base_Score_Text, 
CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(pluginText,LOCATE('cvss', pluginText), 21),' : ',   
-1),  
DECIMAL(10,1)) AS CVSS_Base_Score_Number 
FROM vulnerabilities_internal
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the query which will give u desired results.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(pluginText,LOCATE('cvss', pluginText), 21) AS CVSS_Base_Score_Text,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(pluginText,
        LOCATE('cvss', pluginText), 21),' : ',-1) as decimal(2,1))
    AS CVSS_Base_Score_Number
FROM vulnerabilities_internal
WHERE LCASE(pluginText) REGEXP '.*cvss.*'
```